# AJAX Returning PHP and head.php (page source)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, restful-url

I have some ajax here:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=site_url('front_office/get_email_list/')?>",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

For some reason, this code returns the desired PHP but it also returns my head.php file.

```
function get_email_list() {
    $center_ids = array(
        /* list of user ids */
    );
    print_r(json_encode($this->user_model->get_email_list($center_ids)));
     /* get_email_list($center_ids)) returns a database query result */
}
```

And finally, my head.php contains your usual `<head>` tags with javascript and css imports.

Output looks something like:

`**** return from php *****<head>header stuff</head>`

I'd rather not parse out the header information but instead just get the PHP output.

**Note**: I am using codeiginiter and I am calling a function within the `front_office` controller.

**Second note**: I know I am not posting anything at the moment, but I will be soon. I tried `GET` but the problem persists.

Comment: Recommend look at implementation of RESTful server for codeiginiter: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: _For some reason, this code returns the desired PHP but it also returns my head.php file._ Thats not all the code from that file. So whatever is sending the head stuff you are not showing us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the view, check request, if it is not ajax, load view, otherwise return json encoded result to your ajax request.

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
   // load view      
}else{
    // Adding header, so jQuery ajax request will know that it is json
    // and result will be parsed immediately
   $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
   $this->output->set_output(json_encode($email_list_result));
}
```

More about returning JSON at:
[Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Also, check if you are loading head.php in constructor method ?
Please, post whole code from controller.